# Why Cypress can't detect running webserver?

Tags: docker, cypress

My containers are all running and I'm trying to run Cypress tests agaisnt it:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    expose:
      - 5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
      - SECRET_KEY='hakuna matata'
    depends_on:
      - users-db

  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - users

  users-db:
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - users
      - client
```

cypress.json:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://nginx:80",
    "video": false
}
```

docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
97f91a4b3a81   tdd_nginx      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           tdd_nginx_1
089cd20326c1   tdd_client     "npm start"              56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes   0.0.0.0:3007->3000/tcp, :::3007->3000/tcp   tdd_client_1
85dc333cc487   tdd_users      "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes   5000/tcp                                    tdd_users_1
696298d0ab2c   tdd_users-db   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes   5432/tcp                                    tdd_users-db_1
```

error output:

```
Cypress could not verify that the server set as your `baseUrl` is running:           

> http://nginx:80                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                 
Your tests likely make requests to this `baseUrl` and these tests will fail if you do
n't boot your server.                                                                
                                                                                                                                                 
Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

giving it `http://localhost` didn't work either.
I'm running the test runner from container: `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:3.2.0`

**environment:**

docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396

Cypress  3.2.0

OS: Ubuntu Linux 20.04

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: When all your containers are running, open a browser and go to `http://nginx:80`  or `http://localhost:80`, do they work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your [host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) when running Cypress in this case, as `http://nginx:80` is not accessible from cypress if you are not using the same `docker network`. You either have to run it using the same network created by Docker Compose or bind the Cypress containers network to the host network via:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --network=host --ipc=host cypress/included:3.2.0
```

And now target `localhost:80` instead of `nginx:80`.